# Selecting saveas button when downloading file from browser

Tags: python, selenium, download, microsoft-edge, save-as

I've written a code with selenium and  pyautogui to click around on a website and be able to click the save button with pyautogui after the download button has been clicked with selenium. I wanted to know if it was possible to click the saveas button instead and change the file name with python.

the code I have:

```
driver.find_by_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='Ribbon.Library.Action.ExportToSpreadsheet-Medium']").click()

saveButton = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("C:\\User\\Documents\\savebutton.jpg")
pyautogui.click(position[0], position[1])
```

so what this does is click the download button and then compares the picture of the button and clicks the save option. But theres an arrow on the button to click saveas and that's what I need to click so I can choose the destination to save it and change the name of the file. Was wondering if there is a way to do this.

the button looks like this [image: image of save button]

also I am downloading from Edge, I'm not looking to use chrome or any other browser.

Comment: 1) Do you see any save as button on Edge? Does [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wz4mErlgsxI) help to make the button appear?

2) Is this an option? : Do `pyautogui.click(button='right')  # right-click the mouse` then locate the `Save as ...` in the popup menu.

Comment: right click does not make the saveas appear, and i'd rather find a different way then have to touch the registry.

Comment: How about [this trick](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/46038-turn-off-download-save-prompt-microsoft-edge.html) (ask me what to do with each download)

Comment: why dont you just use an http library to download?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg The button that prompts the save button to appear does not have a url address. It takes data from share point and convert it to an internet query. At least I don't think it has a URL when I inspected the element it doesn't seem to have one.